# Is there a name for the technique of using synthetic division to shift polynomials?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Is there a name for the technique of using synthetic division to shift polynomials?

For example, to shift f(x)=$x^3$+3$x^2$+3x+1 one unit to the left, I can get the remainders from the [synthetic division like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvTRp.jpg) to get f(x+1)=$x^3$+6$x^2$+12x+8.

Comment: It helped if you spelled out *which* division that is i.e. what is the divisor, quotient and remainder. $\;f(x)=(x+1)^3\,$ may not be the best example to choose here.

Comment: You're essentially implementing a variant of the Euclidian algorithm. For example, at the first step we calculate $x^3 + 3x^2 + 3x +1 = (x^2+4x+7)(x-1)+8$, and in the second step we calculate $x^2+4x+7 = (x+5)(x-1)+12$. If we continue and then plug everything in going backward, we get $x^3 + 3x^2 + 3x + 1 = (x-1)^3 + 6(x-1)^2 + 12(x-1) + 8$. Replacing $x$ by $x+1$ yields your claim. It's basically a greedy algorithm to keep replacing polynomials with multiples of $(x-1)$ until we are left with a constant.